# How to implement a strategy pattern for Vue components

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, polymorphism, strategy-pattern

So here's the thing. I have a `Cat`, `Dog` and `Horse` which all implement the `Animal` interface. For each of these I have a `DogComponent`, `CatComponent` and `HorseComponent`.

Question:

How do I create an `AnimalComponent` component that takes any `Animal` but renders `DogComponent` in the case it's a `Dog` without using `switch-case` or a bunch of `v-if`s in the `<template>`?

Please assume that just rendering a different `imageUrl` and `title` is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Vue dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) :)

This special component renders a component given the name provided in the `is` property.

```html
<template>
  <component v-for="animal in animals" :is="`${animal.type}-component`"/>
</template>

<script>
// vue syntax omitted for simplicity
animals: [
  { type: 'dog' },
  { type: 'cat' },
]
</script>
```